# Do Gods really exist physically?

Tags: brahman

Every thing is a manifestation of bhraman, humans, cats dogs and other things. So do Gods like SHIVA VISHNU and and Brahma really exist in physical world or they exist in spiritual world.

Comment: They really exist, and they have a higher degree of existence then us, and they exist beyond the physical, without any body.